# google play says my device is not compatible

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, google-play

My old phone is Samsung galaxy sgh-t959. I installed it directly from eclipse and it works fine. When I upload it to Google play developer console it says that my phone is not compatible. Then, I checked my manifest file and is good. I checked my project.properties not sure if that's the problem because it uses android-19, but how come it works directly from eclipse?

here is my manifest code:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.drakeillusion.yao"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity android:name="com.example.yao.about" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>


      <activity android:name="com.example.yao.am" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.dbm" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.yao.editdeckedit" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>


          <activity android:name="com.example.yao.modifydeckedit" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>



        <activity android:name="com.example.yao.dm"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>



         <activity android:name="com.example.yao.home"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

          <activity android:name="com.example.yao.homedeckedit"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

           <activity android:name="com.example.yao.homedeletedeckedit"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.example.yao.homeeditdeckedit"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

           <activity android:name="com.example.yao.homenewdeckedit"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

     <activity android:name="com.example.yao.MainActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

          <activity android:name="com.example.yao.newdeckedit" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

          <activity android:name="com.example.yao.om" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

<activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdeckeditdeck" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonsters" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonstersextra" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonstersside" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>


            <activity android:name="com.example.yao.resultsearch"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>     

<activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdeckeditdeck2CLEAR" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonsters2CLEAR" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonstersextra2CLEAR" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonstersside2CLEAR" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdeckeditdeck2MODIFY" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonsters2MODIFY" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonstersextra2MODIFY" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.viewdetailmonstersside2MODIFY" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

   <activity android:name="com.example.yao.TextPopupActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

 <activity android:name="com.example.yao.templateactivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>


       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.HelloTabActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.TestPopupActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

           <activity android:name="com.example.yao.deletedeckedit"/>
  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.proprestict" />
  <activity android:name="com.example.yao.FrameLayoutBody" />
           <activity android:name="com.example.yao.loadingtask"  />

        <activity android:name="com.example.yao.RecipesDataSource" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.yao.RecipesDataSourceAdaptor" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.RecipesDataSourceContent" /> 

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.poprestict" />


       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAOhomedeckedit" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

       <!-- tables -->
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAODeckList" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAODeckHieraticBlue" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAODeckDragonGod" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAODeckKingChaos" />

       <!-- DATABASE HELPER AND SQL QUERIES -->
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAOMySQLiteHelper" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAODeckListDataSource" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.YAOGetDataSource2" /> 

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.deckedit" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

       <!-- DETAIL EXPANATION OF THE CARD -->

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.CardDetail" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>


       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.zCardDetail" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

       <!-- CUSTOME LISTVIEW IMAGEVIEW, TEXT AND MORE  -->

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.zCustomListActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>         

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.zCustomeUsersAdapter" />


       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.XCustomListActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>         

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.XCustomeUsersAdapter" />

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.zresultsearch" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.actualeditdeck" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.zactualeditdeck" />


       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.MainActivity2" />



       <!-- lOADING BAR SCREEN -->

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.AddorDeleteCardMenu"      
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>         

            <!-- method 2 Services for expansion files downloads -->

     <activity   android:name="com.example.yao.SplashActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

    <activity android:name="com.example.yao.EHShowCase" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.yao.EHVideoPlayer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.yao.EHImageViewer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

    <service android:name="com.example.yao.EHDownloaderService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.example.yao.EHDownloadBroadcastReceiver" />

    <provider android:name="com.example.yao.EHZipUriProvider" android:authorities="com.example.yao.EHZipUriProvider" />  

       <activity android:name="com.example.yao.MyTabActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>

    <!-- MAIN CLASS CALLING (THE FIRST THING IS CALLED WHEN LOADING) -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.yao.EHExpansionFiles"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >

     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

            <!-- method 1 Services for expansion files downloads -->
             <service android:name="com.example.yao.ExpansionFileDownloaderService" android:label="@string/app_name" />
<receiver android:name="com.example.yao.ExpansionFileAlarmReceiver" android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>

<!-- Required for exapnsion files -->


             <!-- Required to access Google Play Licensing -->
          <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
           <!-- Required to download files from Google Play -->
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
           <!-- Required to keep CPU alive while downloading files
              (NOT to keep screen awake) -->
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
           <!-- Required to poll the state of the network connection
              and respond to changes -->
          <uses-permission
              android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
           <!-- Required to check whether Wi-Fi is enabled -->
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
           <!-- Required to read and write the expansion files on shared storage -->
          <uses-permission
              android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />





       </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you can try here.

- What version of the Android OS does your phone run? Upgrade to the latest
- Try using the latest platform version (21 as at time of writing).
- change the `TargetSDKVersion` to the latest platform version

  `android:targetSdkVersion="21"`
- Try installing the app on a friend's phone to see if you get the same problem